# php mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php

This is my code

```
$conn = mysql_connect($serverName, $username, $password)
        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $selected = mysql_select_db($databaseName,$conn)
        or die("Could not find the database");
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` () VALUES ()");
    return mysqli_insert_id($result)
```

This is the exception

```
Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in C:\xampp2\htdocs\XXX\controllers\User.php on line 24
```

and the line 24 is `return mysqli_insert_id($result)`

Comment: You're mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`. They aren't related.

Comment: I think there are thousands of questions on SO posted by beginners that start learning PHP and MySQL with the `mysql_*` functions. Most of these questions have comments and answers and comments to answers that say "DO NOT use mysql, use mysqli or PDO". I bet in 2020 there still will be newbies asking where is the bug in their `mysql_query() or die()` code. :'-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using mysql with mysqli. You cannot use both, you must choose which MySQL extension you want to use.

If mysqli:

Try using the [mysqli connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) and the [mysqli select db](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

If mysql:

use [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)(), not mysqli_insert_id()

I would use PDO myself, mysql is depricated:

```
try 
{
    // Connect to your database
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    // Put your insert statement
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `user` () VALUES ()";

    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);

    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();

    echo "New record created successfully. Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br />" . $e->getMessage();
}
```

**Updated:** 
[The MySQL extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php): has been removed and is no longer available

Answer (score 3):

You have to be consistent about which MySQL extension you're using. If you're using the `mysql` extension, you must use `mysql_insert_id()`, not `mysqli_insert_id()`.

It would be better if you rewrote all your code to use the `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions, as the `mysql` extension is deprecated. But it's not a drop-in replacement, the syntax is somewhat different.

Answer (score 0):

You mix `mysql` with `mysqli` and the `boolean` mentioned in the error message is  `FALSE`. Your `INSERT` query failed because it does not provide any values to be inserted. It has syntax errors on `()`.

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user` (`name`) VALUES ('John Doe')");
return mysql_insert_id($result);
```

**DO NOT** use `mysql_*` functions. The `mysql` extension is [deprecated since PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) and will be removed in the future. Use either [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score -1):

Mixed mysql_ and mysqli. Try

```
mysql_insert_id();
```

instead. If failed.

```
mysql_query("SELECT last_insert_id()");
```

should work for you.